# swf file in subfolder not loading

Tags: xhtml, flash

The code below on works when my xml and swf file are located in the same directory as the html file. However, when i move both file to a sub directory, nothing shows. I have tried using the absolute path but not much luck. Please help.

```
 <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" width="110" height="110" bgcolor="#f0eee1">
            <param name="movie" value="flash/Main.swf?xml_path=flash/Settings.xml" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <embed src="flash/Main.swf?xml_path=flash/Settings.xml" quality="high" width="110" height="110" bgcolor="#f0eee1" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
```

Comment: To confirm your absolute paths were correct could you post them here for us to see?

Comment: @jhocking, but i am developing on my localmachine, so of what significance is that?

Answer (score 0):

Flash will try to interpret any relative paths as relative to your HTML file. If I had to guess, Flash is misplacing your XML file.

How about adding a `base` attribute to your `object` and`embed` tags? `base` will let you specify just where relative links should be relative from; in this case, you could supply the absolute path to your subdirectory and Flash will begin looking there for your XML file.

[Here's Adobe's write-up on `base`](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/041/tn_04157.html) and how to get started using it.

Comment: thanks for that pointer, it loads well on internet explorer but still not working on other browsers like chrome or firefox. any ideas, and yes i did use the absolute path.